# Transferring specific data from one sheet to another in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Thank you for taking your time.

I have a question in relation to a Google Sheet document that I'm working on improving to keep a even better overview of my investments and possibilities.

The document consists of various Scandinavian stocks (on different sheets) were I'm importing quarterly statements for each company through an ImportXML function. The number of ImportXML functions does often make the rows apear either as "Loading..." or "Error".

I did find a Google script in here where I'm able to transfer data from one sheet to another, and hereby save data in case of a sudden "Loading..." issue for all rows at the same time.

**However is it possible to include a function where it doesn't overwrite in sheet 2 if specific text/data is mentioned in a cell in sheet 1? I don't want cells with the naming "Loading..." or "Error" to be transferred.**

This is the script I have been using:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sourceSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = sourceSS.getSheetByName("DK Large Cap 0");
  var targetSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var targetSheet = targetSS.getSheetByName("DK Large Cap");

  var ranges = ["A1:J51"];
  ranges.forEach(range => {
    var data = sourceSheet.getRange(range).getValues();
    targetSheet.getRange(range).setValues(data);
  })
}
```

Thank you for the time you take on this. It is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction() {
  const s = 'Loading...'
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  var tsh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  
  var ranges = ["A1:I33"];
  ranges.forEach(rg => {
    let rng = sh.getRange(rg);
    var vs = rng.getValues();
    let row = rng.getRow();
    let col = rng.getColumn();
    vs.forEach((r,i) => {
      r.forEach((c,j) => {
        if(!c.toString().includes(s)) {
          tsh.getRange(row + i, col + j).setValue(vs[i][j])
        }
      })
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: Sorry if I'm not totally clear about what I'm looking for. What I'm looking for is to not copy-paste cells with the text/value "Loading..." from Sheet 1 to Sheet 2. The code I have does copy-paste all cells from A1 to I33 without taking into consideration what is written in each cell. I hope it is better understood? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Cooper, I can see that you have now edited your comment. Thanks for the code. However it doesn't work as it still overwrites in Sheet 2 with the "Loading..." cells from Sheet 1. The difference is just that it now writes it as "#ERROR!" instead in Sheet2.

Comment: It worked for me when I tested it

Comment: It doesn't work with the importhtml formulas I have. It does still overwrite with Loading... and #ERROR!

Comment: I have kept trying for some hours now and I can't get it to work as it transfers the "Loading..." text in Sheet 1 into "#ERROR!" in Sheet 2. I have tried to change the const s to "#ERROR!" but it results in nothing getting transferred.

Comment: I don't have any way of testing with importhtml formulas because I never use formulas

Comment: I do mention the fact that the sheet consists of those formulas and it is those formulas who are giving me problems with the "Loading..." cells. Anyway thanks for the effort.

Comment: You differentiate between values and formulas by using getFormulas() in a 2d array and modify the write routine.